# Mojolicious - two non-blocking GET requests in the same controller

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm writing a Mojolicious module/controller that needs to make two GET requests; one after the other. The second GET request depends on response data from the first.

I would like both requests to be non-blocking. However I can't easily "return" from the context of the first non-blocking callback to supply values to the second request.

```
sub my_controller {

    my ($self) = @_;

    $self->ua->get($first_endpoint, sub {
        # handle response - extract value for second request?
    }); 

    my $second_endpoint = 'parameter not available here';

    $self->ua->get($second_endpoint, sub {}); 

}
```

I would prefer not to nest the second request into the first callback if possible?

Comment: If the second one depends on the first, and would not be done if the first one fails, nesting is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Nesting is how you specify the sequence of two operations when dealing with non-blocking calls, why would you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

First need to call `render_later` method in controller because you write non-blocking code.

Exist 2 ways how to pass data:

1)

```
sub  action_in_controller {
  my $c = shift->render_later;

  $c->delay(
    sub {
      my $delay = shift;

      $c->ua->get('http://one.com' => $delay->begin);
    },
    sub {
      my ($delay, $tx) = @_;

      $c->ua->post('http://second.com' => $delay->begin);
    },
    sub {
      my ($delay, $tx) = @_;

      $c->render(text => 'la-la-la');
    }
  );
}
```

2)

```perl
sub action_in_controller {
  my $c = shift->render_later;

  $c->ua->get('http://one.com' => sub {
    my ($ua, $tx) = @_;

    $c->ua->post('http://second.com' => sub {
      my ($ua, $tx) = @_;

      $c->render(text => 'la-la-la');
    });
  });
}
```

**UPD**

Found another variant of calling using Coro. 
But in perl 5.22 it not work and need to apply [patch](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl5-porters/228699/) to repair it.
You need additionally to write plugin Coro.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/e0eb7e92974d450cfa0aeb7d3fa18fc9) example. You need only `ua.pl` and plugin `Mojolicious::Plugin::Core`.